# How to ignore the error "Exit with code 1 due to network error: ContentNotFoundError" in python?

Tags: python-3.x, error-handling, wkhtmltopdf

I wrote the script to convert the html page to pdf , the script generates a pdf but it gives the error **"Exit with code 1 due to network error: ContentNotFoundError"**, I think we can ignore it using `--load-error-handling ignore` but I don't know how to use it with python. I am working with Anaconda Spyder Python 3.7.
My script is below:

```
import pdfkit

try:
    import urlparse
    from urllib import urlencode
except: # For Python 3
    import urllib.parse as urlparse
    from urllib.parse import urlencode

# url = "http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=question"
# params = {'lang':'en','tag':'python'}

photoid = 3
seaid_destination = 4    
search = "merge_recog"

url = "http://localhost:8080/" + search + "?"
params = {'photoid':photoid,'seaid_destination':seaid_destination}

url_parse = urlparse.urlparse(url)
query = url_parse.query            #retrieve query item
url_dict = dict(urlparse.parse_qsl(query))     #convert the list to dict
url_dict.update(params)                  #add params to dict
url_new_query = urlencode(url_dict)            #convert it in "percent-encoded"
url_parse = url_parse._replace(query=url_new_query)   #replace old query with new query
new_url = urlparse.urlunparse(url_parse)        #construct new url
print(new_url)

config = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf="/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf")
pdfkit.from_url(new_url, search+"_"+str(photoid)+"_"+str(seaid_destination)+'.pdf',
                configuration = config)
```

Answer (score 3):

Same problem here. As you have noticed, according to their [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/pdfkit/), the only available configuration options are *wkhtmltopdf* and *meta_tag_prefix*.

Unfortunately, I ended up doing:

```
try:
    pdfkit.from_file(path, new_path)
except OSError as e:
    if 'Done' not in str(e):
        raise e
```

Assuming the word "Done" won't appear when *pdfkit* couldn't generate the output file, I ensure the existence of the word "Done" in the exception string.
Pretty bad solution. I hope they'll fix it anytime soon.